# html js css math function

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

I am building a page where i have a grid of 8 buttons and 9 radio type input.
I gave every button a value and created a function that print on a div the value (it's like a tax if you want to give back an item to the store, something like that).
Now i'm trying to create the second part. It consist in: You have to choose 3 thing: 1- the category of the item (the 8 button grid), 2- the lenght/widht/height if the package for the item and 3- the weight of the item (the last 2 are both radio type button).
In the same div where i print the thing i tlked about in the first part, i have 2 other places where I have to print 2 other value.
The problem is that, for example for the right one, i have a excel file with all the math i have to do to gain the right result (there's a base value in cent for every button and a value for every lenght/widht/height "combination".
the fact is that i cannot have more than one value for button, so I red online that you can use for example "data-value" and I tryed but i think the sintax to use it is different cause it didn't work, so I tried something else and i'm gonna show you cause i taught it was gonna work. ( I took the same function I used for part 1 and added something to make me complete also the other one. I'm gonna let u see the base version of the function commented and the one I tried normally).

```js
/*document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio], button').forEach(function(input) {
        
            input.onclick = function() {
                
                var price;
                var stockT;
                var stock;
                var vol;

                if (this.value == '1,56') {
                    price = '1,56';

                } 
                else if (this.value == '1,04'){
                    price = '1,04';
                }
                else if (this.value == '1,30'){
                    price = '1,30';
                }
                else if (this.value == '1,17'){
                    price = '1,17';
                }

                if (this.value == '1,56'  && this.value == '4960') {
                    stock = '0,00002';
                    vol = '4960';
                    stockT = stock * vol;

                }
           
                
                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[1].innerText = price;
                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[2].innerText = stockT;
            };  
        })*/
        
        
        
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio], button').forEach(function(input) {
        
            input.onclick = function() {
                
                var price;
                var stockT;
                var stock;
                var vol;

                if (this.value == '1,56') {
                    price = '1,56';

                } 
                else if (this.value == '1,04'){
                    price = '1,04';
                }
                else if (this.value == '1,30'){
                    price = '1,30';
                }
                else if (this.value == '1,17'){
                    price = '1,17';
                }

                if (this.value == '1,56'  && this.value == '4960') {
                    stock = '0,00002';
                    vol = '4960';
                    stockT = stock * vol;

                }
           
                
                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[1].innerText = price;
                document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[2].innerText = vol;
            };  
        })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.justify {
  justify-content: center;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}

.evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.tabtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tariffe {
  font-size: small;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
}

.tartitle {
  font-size: medium;
}

div h2 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.m-7 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.m-14 {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.richiedi {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.tabcosti {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.border {
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.m-left-50 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.x-small {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.tabcosti2 {
  border-top: 0px;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.info {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
}

.info2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  font-size: small;
}

.unbtn {
  border: 0px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.unbtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}


.btn {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}

.btn2{
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container" class="justify evenly flex-row">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,56">Abbigliamento e Scarpe</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel2" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Pet & Food</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel3" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Sport e Tempo libero</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel4" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Elettronica e Informatica</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel5" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Casa e Cucina</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel6" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Auto e Moto</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel7" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,17">Food & Beverage</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-row">
                        <button id="sel8" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Belleza e Salute</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            

            <div id="radio" class="justify m-30 evenly flex-row bg">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="4960"> 31x16x10
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="9900"> 33x20x15
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="14875"> 35x25x17
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="24800"> 40x31x20
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="35000"> 40x35x25
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="49200"> 41x40x30
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="74925"> 45x45x37
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="100000"> 50x50x40
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="150000"> 60x50x50
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="radio2" class="flex-row bg m-7 justify evenly">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="1" name="Peso"> 0-1 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="2" name="Peso"> 1-2 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="3" name="Peso"> 2-3 kg
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="4" name="Peso"> 3-5 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="7" name="Peso"> 5-7 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="10" name="Peso"> 7-10 kg
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="15" name="Peso"> 10-15 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="20" name="Peso"> 15-20 kg
                    </div>
                    <div class="align flex-row">
                        <input class="cont" type="radio" value="30" name="Peso"> 20-30 kg
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="justify evenly flex-row">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>TARIFFA DI GESTIONE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>TARIFFA DI RESO</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>TARIFFA DI STOCCAGGIO</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tabcosti evenly justify flex-row">
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p id="reso">€ <span class="white"></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>€ <span class="white"></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-col">
                    <p>€ <span class="white"></span> <span class="x-small">al mese</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You asked the same question a few days ago and the point I made about the complex values still stands. How are these values `40x31x20` etc to be used in the calculations? Same for weights such as `15-20 kg` ~ these values make the creation of a useful function very hard - especially when the rules are very unclear

Comment: i did a similar question, u are right.
To answer ur comment, you are right, i forgot to update the code i put in the snippet. i'm gonna do it now

Comment: `'0,00002'` isn’t a valid numeric string, so `coso * vol` will always be `NaN`. Luckily, `stockT` is never used and `this.value == '1,56'  && this.value == '31x16x10'` will never be true, so this part can be removed. Attributes like `data-value` are accessed like [`.dataset.value`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset); just read the documentation. Please [edit] your post and make it look less like a wall of text. What you need to do, what is the problem, what have you tried, what are the actual and the desired results, are there any errors (see dev tools)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon how can i make '0,00002' work?

Comment: @FilippoCanino Have you tried using actual numbers? `0.00002`

Comment: @SebastianSimon thx i'm dumb and i didn't realize. Now i used it as an actual number and the first part (the one about the tax) works fine, but when i click on a radio type button, the value of "the first part" is changed into "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that the buttons and radio inputs affect different things (buttons affect `price`, radio inputs affect `vol`). These need to be separated to different events, with the results of each stored in different variables. Numeric values also need to be used for calculations. Here is a simple example that resolves these:

```js
var price;
var stockT;
var stock;
var vol;
var coso;
    
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(input) {
  input.onclick = function() {
    price = this.value;
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[1].innerText = price;
  };
})
    
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(function(input) {
  input.onchange = function() {
    if (price == '1,56' && this.value == '31x16x10') {
      coso = 0.00002;
      vol = 4960;
      stockT = coso * vol;
    } else {
      //other vol calculations go here so it is not undefined
      vol = 1;
    }
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabcosti .white')[2].innerText = vol;
  };
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.justify {
  justify-content: center;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}

.evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.tabtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tariffe {
  font-size: small;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
}

.tartitle {
  font-size: medium;
}

div h2 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cont2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.m-7 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.m-14 {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.richiedi {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.tabcosti {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.border {
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.m-left-50 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.x-small {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.tabcosti2 {
  border-top: 0px;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.info {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
}

.info2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  font-size: small;
}

.unbtn {
  border: 0px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.unbtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container" class="justify evenly flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,56">Abbigliamento e Scarpe</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel2" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Pet & Food</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel3" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Sport e Tempo libero</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel4" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Elettronica e Informatica</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel5" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,04">Casa e Cucina</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel6" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Auto e Moto</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel7" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,17">Food & Beverage</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <button id="sel8" class="btn bottoneCategoria" value="1,30">Belleza e Salute</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>




<div id="radio" class="justify m-30 evenly flex-row bg">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="31x16x10"> 31x16x10
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="33x20x15"> 33x20x15
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="35x25x17"> 35x25x17
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="40x31x20"> 40x31x20
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="40x35x25"> 40x35x25
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="41x40x30"> 41x40x30
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="45x45x37"> 45x45x37
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="50x50x40"> 50x50x40
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="60x50x50"> 60x50x50
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="radio2" class="flex-row bg m-7 justify evenly">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="0-1 kg" name="Peso"> 0-1 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="1-2 kg" name="Peso"> 1-2 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="2-3 kg" name="Peso"> 2-3 kg
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="3-5 kg" name="Peso"> 3-5 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="5-7 kg" name="Peso"> 5-7 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="7-10 kg" name="Peso"> 7-10 kg
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="10-15 kg" name="Peso"> 10-15 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="15-20 kg" name="Peso"> 15-20 kg
    </div>
    <div class="align flex-row">
      <input class="cont" type="radio" value="20-30 kg" name="Peso"> 20-30 kg
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="justify evenly flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>TARIFFA DI GESTIONE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>TARIFFA DI RESO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>TARIFFA DI STOCCAGGIO</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabcosti evenly justify flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p id="reso">€ <span class="white"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>€ <span class="white"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>€ <span class="white"></span> <span class="x-small">al mese</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. but now i have 2 problem
1 how can i round up the result of the function to the second decimal figure (instead of having 1,357 i'd like to have 1,36)
2 now if i click on a radio type, and then on another, i'll have both of them visually activated. how can i solve this?
(Now i just need a suggestion. How should i do to implement this function for all the other button and radio type? I tried to copy paste it but it stop working)

Comment: I solved alone the problem about the radio type being visually active together, i deleted the name of the radio type and forgot to put it back

Comment: i also solved the rounding up problem. now there's the one about having the function to work also with the other button (not radio type as i said before, my mistake). I copy pasted it, changing value to make it work with the second button and it work, but now, if i try with the first button, where i should receive the output, it says NaN

Comment: Without seeing what you've done, it's very difficult to know what the solution is. If you're getting a `NaN` error, it's most likely because you are trying to multiply a piece of text with a number, for example. For this, you will need to use [parseFloat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp).